# pd.read_excel hangs when I run from executable program

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am loading an .xlsx file into a dataframe. When I run the program from Pycharm or Jupyter notebook, it runs without any problems.

df = pd.read_excel(file_name)

But, when I create an executable file through Pyinstaller, the program hangs soon after I run pd.read_excel(file) command. I tried to read the file as .csv (after converting the excel to csv) as well and faced the same problem.

Following is the pyinstaller command I am using:

pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=icon.ico main.py

Let me know if anyone could help!

Comment: Try to run the executable from the console and see the output. It might be because the ```read_excel``` cant find the file.

Comment: I did run from the command prompt and it gave the error "ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd". I installed xlrd via "pip install xlrd" and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The xlrd library need to be installed from command prompt for python interpreter. I am sure this will help others who may face similar issue!